Movie where teenagers try to kill a yellow monster/zombie by cremating it
I'm trying to find this movie that I watched when I was about 10 years old.
Looks like an 80's B horror movie. I think it was probably an american movie, but it was dubbed in portuguese, so I can't know with certainty.
I only remember this one scene:  
There are some teenagers (maybe four) at a cemetery at night and they are trying to cremate a yellow monster/zombie because they couldn't kill in another way. So they chop him up in small pieces and put the pieces in plastic bags(the body parts still moving) then throw it in the oven at the crematorium, there's a lot of smoke and they leave the room but I'm not sure if the monster really died or not.
These are "older" teenagers, probably 17-18 years old. And the protagonist was male.
And that's about all I can remember, I hope it is enough.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Oh, I forgot about the country. I think it was probably an american movie, but it was dubbed in portuguese, so I can't know with certainty.

Sounds like one of the Return of the Living Dead movies.

Return of the Living Dead (1985) 
An army cannister in a warehouse near cemetary contains a zombie. The cannister is breached infecting all previously dead life forms in warehouse including butterflies, split dogs and a yellowish cadaver. 
The warehouse employees decapitate the zombie and take body parts in black bags to a friend who works at crematorium in the adjacent cemetary. The zombie is cremated, the fumes rise up through smoke stack to the sky and it rains infecting the cemetary and causing a zombie outbreak. 
One of the men who decapitates the zombie is Clu Gulager from A Nightmare on Elm Street 2 and Feast. 

That's it! Thank you! There weren't any teenagers after all.

Damn! I actually thought about this movie when I read the question, should've posted an answer...
